# Writing a string through serial port (c++ Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, string, serial-port, port

I have made a small program that connects to a serial port that is connected to a robot. This robot will respond to coordinates I send to it.

Therefore I want to send a string of coordinates to it, through the serial connection.

Here is some of the code that I have come up with, not including connecting to the serial port, as I can do that without issue.

```
std::string moveString = "X-249 Y250 Z-550\n";

moveString.c_str();

std::cout << "SENDING MESSAGE" << "--> " << moveString << std::endl;
write(serial_port, moveString.c_str(), sizeof(moveString));

close(serial_port);
```

I create a string, then I want to send that using write()
My issue is that the robot will not respond to it.

I tried recreating the code in Python like so: (it's quite a lot simpler in Python...)

```
ser.write("X249 Y-250 Z-550\n")

ser.close()
```

And the Python code works perfectly fine, no issue.
I've tried looking up solutions, but I keep seeing different ways of doing it and I have a hard time making sense of it.

Please answer as simple as possible, I am still pretty new to C++.

Comment: You will be surprised to learn that your `sizeof(moveString)` will give you the same result whether your string is empty or contains the complete contents of "Harry Potter And The Philosopher's Stone". `sizeof()` doesn't do what you think it does. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: Wow! I changed
--> "write(serial_port, moveString.c_str(), sizeof(moveString));"
to -->
"write(serial_port, moveString.c_str(), moveString.size());"
and now it works... god you have no idea how long I have fumbled with this, thank you!